# CMake cannot find my library file

Tags: cmake

I want to use CMake to create a simple static library `Maths`, and then link to that library to create a simple executable `Alpha`.

Here's my directory structure:

```
/Maths
    /build
        /
    /CMakeLists.txt
    /maths.cpp
    /maths.h
/Alpha
    /build
        /
    /CMakeLists.txt
    /main.cpp
```

And here are the contents of those files:

*** CMakeLists.txt (for Maths) ***

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(Maths)
add_library(maths STATIC maths.cpp)
```

*** maths.cpp ***

```
int Double(int x)
{
    int y = x * 2;
    return y;
}
```

*** maths.h ***

```
int Double(int x);
```

*** CMakeLists.txt (for Alpha) ***

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Alpha)
add_executable(alpha main.cpp ../Maths/maths.h)
target_link_libraries(maths ../Maths/build/libmaths.a)
```

*** main.cpp ***

```
#include <iostream>

#include "maths.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = Triple(x);
    cout << "The answer = " << y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So, I enter the directory `/Maths/build`, and run `cmake ..`. Then, I run `make`. This creates the library file `libmaths.a` in the directory `/Maths/build`.

Then, I enter the directory `/Alpha/build`, and run `cmake ..`. Then, I run `make`. However, this gives me the error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmaths
```

Why can make not find the library file that I just created?

I also tried copyiing `libmaths.a` and `maths.h` into the directory `/Alpha`, and changing Alpha's CMakeLists.txt to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Alpha)
add_executable(alpha main.cpp maths.h)
target_link_libraries(maths libmaths.a)
```

But this gave the same error.

Answer (score 5):

The essential problem here is that `libmaths.a` is not placed in one of the default linker directories.
The bigger problem is that you passed `libmaths.a` to `target_link_libraries` in the first place.

This is bad for several reasons, but the most obvious is that it's completely non-portable. A different compiler toolchain might use a different ending than `.a` for static libraries, so you won't be able to build there. Also, should you ever decide to switch to dynamic linking in the future, it means refactoring your existing CMake scripts.

The proper solution is to not pass hardcoded filenames to `target_link_libraries`. There are two roads that you can take to avoid this.

1. Use a find script. Essentially, you call [`find_library(MY_MATHLIB maths [...])`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) and then do `target_link_libraries(alpha ${MY_MATHLIB})` instead. This will determine the absolute path of the `.a` file in a portable way and pass that to the linker. The biggest disadvantage of this approach is that the `.a` file must already be there for the find call to succeed. So if you want to build `maths` *after* running the CMake for `alpha` or build it as part of `alpha`, this won't work.
2. Since both libraries are under your control, consider using [CMake's packaging mechanism](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#using-packages). This is by far the most convenient approach for building, but unfortunately also the most difficult to set up. If you are willing to spend some time digging through the CMake docs and experimenting with the build, I encourage you to give it a try, but if you just want something that works quickly, you might want to stick with option 1.

Comment: I am also having the same problem here and also just getting started to cmake. I don't know anything about C++ programming practices, just getting started. Could you explain your first recomendation? Because I couldn't understand a thing in the provided link. If you can give an example I would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Bora The `find_library` command simply looks for the library file on disk. Since CMake knows the naming convention of the different compilers, you just give the raw name (`maths` in the example) without any file extensions and CMake will automatically search for the right file. Depending on your system and the file's location, you still might need to give additional hints where the file is located. Take a look at the linked manpage for a full explanation of the lookup rules. But in the end it's really nothing more than searching for a file with the matching name on disk.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `CMakeLists.txt` in the root directory

**/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT( MyProject )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( Maths )
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( Alpha )
```

**in Alpha/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( alpha maths )
```

Run CMake on the top-level CMakeLists.txt instead of the individual subdirectory ones